# Importance of Q(Saturation Flag) in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm, processor, instruction-set, saturation-arithmetic

I want to understand the importance of Q flag in ARM Processor. I know there are certain instructions like QADD,QSUB etc.

But I need to understand this with some examples which will clarify the concept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is explained in the "ARM Architecture Reference Manual" (ARM DDI 0100E):

Bit[27] of the `CPSR` is a *sticky overflow* flag, also known as the Q flag. This flag is set to 1 if any of the following occurs:

- Saturation of the addition result in a `QADD` or `QDADD` instruction
- Saturation of the subtraction result in a `QSUB` or `QDSUB` instruction
- Saturation of the doubling intermediate result in a `QDADD` or `QDSUB` instruction
- Signed overflow during an `SMLA<x><y>` or `SMLAW<y>` instruction

The Q flag is *sticky* in that once it has been set to 1, it is not affected by whether subsequent calculations saturate and/or overflow. Its intended usage is:

1. Use an `MSR CPSR_f,#0` instruction to clear the Q flag (this also clears the condition code flags).
2. Peform a sequence of calculations.
3. Use an `MRS Rn,CPSR` instruction to read the `CPSR`, then test the value of the Q flag. If it is still 0, none of the above types of saturation or overflow occured during step 2.
   Otherwise, at least one instance of stauration or overflow occured.

---

An example:

```
mov     r2,#0x70000000
qadd    r3,r2,r2
```

`0x70000000 + 0x70000000` would become `0xE0000000`, but since `qadd` is saturating, the result is saturated to `0x7FFFFFFF` (the largest positive 32-bit integer) and the Q flag is set.

Comment: Thank you Michael. The example is what I was looking for..:)